# Як узгодити присудок з підметом? Він буде вправнИМ, чи вправнИЙ?

Tags: вибір-слова

Помітила, що деякі пишуть "він буде вправнИМ,  а  деякі він  буде вправнИЙ". Як  правильного?? Не можу знайти віповідного правила.

Comment: Нагадую, tooltip під кнопкою «проголосувати униз» містить напис: *„This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful“*, що у перекладі означає *«це запитання не демонструє зусиль до дослідження; воно неясне або некорисне»*. Сама по собі проблематика узгодження слів у словосполученні — це дуже благодатна тема, і при гідному оформленні можна було б зробити не одне, а цілих декілька «жирних» запитань, які могли б бути позитивно сприйняті спільнотою. Шкода, коли така можливість втрачається.

Answer (score 1):

Для української літератури характерне узгодження слів «бути», «стати» тощо з іменниками/прикметниками (які розглядають як частину складеного іменного присудка або як додаток) і в називному, і в орудному відмінках:

> Обоє вони були сироти, побралися й жили собі двійко (Марко Вовчок);
>   Будь мені лицар да вірнесенький («Українські пісні» М. Максимовича);
>   Не писав до Вас, бо був слабий (М. Коцюбинський);
>   Перепелиха була вже стара людина, добра, жалісна (Панас Мирний);
>
> Вранці на палубі я був першим (М. Ірчан);
>   Один з останніх його рейсів був винятковим (О. Гончар);
>   Отаким точнісінько Іван був… (М. Стельмах);
>   То був волом, а то хочеш зостатися конем (М. Номис).

Історично в давньоруській мові в таких випадках уживався називний відмінок («ти єси князь» — принаймні так [наразі стверджує Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA&oldid=20657215#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)). Нині є схильність до вжитку орудного (так стверджує Антоненко-Давидович ([1](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/nazyvnyj-vidminok-u-skladenomu-prysudku), [2](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53405/33112.html), [3](http://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=4002&page=3), [4](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Antonenko-Davydovych/Yak_my_hovorymo/)); Вікіпедія за наведеним раніше посиланням стверджує, що завжди вживається орудний, але це очевидно є перебільшенням).

Борис Антоненко-Давидович у статті «Називний відмінок у складеному присудку» з «Як ми говоримо» (див. посилання вище) стверджує, що вибраний відмінок залежить від постійності ознаки:

> Що ж — виходить, ніби це однаково, який поставити відмінок іменника в складеному присудку — називний чи орудний? Ні, не однаково. Якщо проаналізувати всі наведені вище приклади, то неважко помітити, що називний відмінок стоїть там, де іменник і прикметник мають незмінну властивість <…>. Зате там, де мовиться про несталу або тимчасову ознаку в іменнику й прикметнику, дають перевагу орудному відмінку <…>.

Але якихось підтверджень цьому я не знайшов, навпаки, наведені Борисом Антоненком-Давидовичем  приклади радше підштовхують мене до думки про поступовий історичний перехід від називного до орудного.

С. О. Караман у «Сучасній українській літературній мові» ([1](http://pidruchniki.com/68721/dokumentoznavstvo/skladeniy_imenniy_prisudok), [2](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=6629)) просто каже про можливість називного і орудного відмінка, не надаючи переваги одному чи іншому (хіба що зазначає, що за умови відсутності дієслова-зв'язки орудний майже не вживається). Також указує на можливість знахідного відмінка з прийменником «за» («був я вам за тата»).